# Hazelcast members don't share entries in Embedded Topology

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I have a small spring boot application, and I'm using Hazelcast (Embedded Cache Topology) for caching. This is the @Configuration class for Hazelcast:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class HazelcastConfig {
public static final String BANKS = "banks";

@Bean
Config config() {
    Config config = new Config();

    MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
    mapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(3000);
    config.getMapConfigs().put(BANKS, mapConfig);

    return config;
}
```

}

Then I add the @Cachable annotation to one of my methods:

```
@Cacheable(HazelcastConfig.BANKS)
public UserAccount findByAccountNumber(String accountNumber){
    logger.info("INSIDE REPO");
    UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount();
    userAccount.setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
    userAccount.setId(new Long(1));
    userAccount.setAddress("via Rossi");
    userAccount.setName("Pippo");

    return userAccount;
}
```

Everything seems to work fine: the first time I call the method, the program enters inside the body of the method itself; from the second time the program get the value from the cache ( the program doesn't enter inside the method body ).
The problems start when I run 2 instances of the application; when I run the second instance I can see that Hazelcast understands that there are 2 members (from the logs):

```
Members {size:2, ver:2} [
Member [172.15.245.39]:5701 - cec4e04a-a8ef-4bd1-9072-5c313ba14666
Member [172.15.245.39]:5702 - bfe7d9a0-dcfd-4a9e-8a10-3e3882e814d2 this
]
```

but these 2 members seem to have 2 separate caches; this is my test:

1. Start instance 1 of application ( tomcat port 8080 )
2. Start instance 2 of application ( tomcat port 8090 )
3. Call the method from instance 1-> the program doesn't use the cache ( OK, because the cache is empty)
4. Call the method from instance 1-> the program use the cache ( OK, because now the cache has the entry)
5. Call the method from instance 2-> the program doesn't use the cache ( **KO**, because I think that tha caches of the two instances should have the same entries).

   Any suggestion?

Comment: Try changing `@Cacheable(HazelcastConfig.BANKS)` to `@Cacheable(value=HazelcastConfig.BANKS, sync=true)`. Does that solve it ?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work for me, same problem.

Comment: Do you have the same issue following this guide: https://guides.hazelcast.org/caching-springboot/?

Comment: What versions are you using ? `sync=true` does it for me, on Spring 2.3.4.RELEASE and Hazelcast 4.0.3 If you can post a full code sample, it should be possible to figure out. Note that setting `sync` is not necessarily an answer, more of an explanation.

Comment: Did you actually make sure that the value is stored in Hazelcast? It looks like you just validated if a method is called or not, but you did not have a look inside Hazelcast itself.

My guess is that a different cache is used here thanks to Spring's autoconfiguration.

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek You are totally right: the problem was that I wasn't using hazelcast but spring boot default mechanism; that because in the pom I had only hazelcast core dependency; adding also hazelcast-spring dependecy resolve the problem. Thanks a lot